# DOMDocument - appendXML() not working with forms

Tags: php, html, forms, append, domdocument

I'm having a problem with appendXML(), it won't append forms to HTML.

Right now I have this code

```
$domdocument = new DOMDocument();
$domdocument->loadHTML($html);
$domlookup = new DOMXPath($domdocument);
$formDivs = $domlookup->query("//*[contains(@class, 'formClass')]");
$frag = $domdocument->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML($formHTML);
for ($i = $formDivs->length - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
    $formDivs->item($i)->parentNode->appendChild($frag);
}
@$html = $domdocument->saveHTML();
```

The code works well and appends to the div with the class "formCLass" simple HTML, like texts and divs with texts. However, when it comes to appending a form...well...that's a different story.

I have also tried to append using

```
$frag->nodeValue = $formHTML;
```

instead of

```
$frag->appendXML($formHTML);
```

But it still didn't work...

Trying

```
$frag->textContent = $formHTML;
```

will output the form as text and this won't work for me, obviously.

How can I solve this problem?

form code:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="fb-text form-group field-petname">
<label for="petname" class="fb-text-label">
"Pet Name"<span class="fb-required">*</span>
</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Pet Name" required = "required" aria-required = "true" class="form-control" name="petname" id="petname">
</div>
<div class="fb-text form-group field-petowner">
<label for="petowner" class="fb-text-label">
"Pet owner"<span class="fb-required">*</span>
</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert owner's name" required = "required" aria-required = "true" class="form-control" name="petowner" id="petowner">
</div>
<div class="fb-text form-group field-phone">
<label for="phone" class="fb-text-label">
"Phone number"<span class="fb-required">*</span>
</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone number" required = "required" aria-required = "true" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone">
</div>
<div>
<div id="goldenmembership">
<i class="fas fa-truck"></i>Free delivery!
</div>
</div>
<div class="fb-select form-group field-brand">
<label for="brand" class="fb-select-label">
What brand would your pet like?<span class="fb-required">*</span>
</label>
<select class="form-control" name="brand" id="brand" required = "required" aria-required = "true">
<option value="3x20" id="brand-1">Hills - 20€</option>
<option value="3x23" id="brand-2">BioPet - 23€</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just put together a really simple test case using your code, with some of my own HTML, and it seems to be appending okay as you'll see below.

Any chance your form's HTML is invalid?

If you're still having issues, could you post up your HTML somewhere so we can try with that, please?

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="formClass">
            <!-- Placeholder -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$formHtml = <<<HTML
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="test"/>
</form>
HTML;

$domdocument = new DOMDocument();
$domdocument->loadHTML($html);
$domlookup = new DOMXPath($domdocument);
$formDivs = $domlookup->query("//*[contains(@class, 'formClass')]");
$frag = $domdocument->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML($formHtml);
for ($i = $formDivs->length - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
    $formDivs->item($i)->parentNode->appendChild($frag);
}
$html = $domdocument->saveHTML();

echo $html;
```

HTML output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="formClass">
            <!-- Placeholder -->
        </div>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="test">
</form></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm really puzzled. For some reason, using your identical value on $formHtml on my server, it won't work :)

Comment: That's strange, what PHP version are you running? I ran this against PHP 7.4, but it should go back way beyond that. Here's an example of it running elsewhere: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6bd404a3cc2f5d1c41a3604696861e8e71360f3

Comment: Just tested back to PHP 5.1.5 and works, so should be pretty safe. Have you tried running exactly my code on your server with nothing else in the script? Does that work?

Comment: Hehe @Aran, your code tricked me a bit, I just made copy->paste and your variable was $formHtml and the my function appendXML was looking for $formHTML. Anyway, yes, it works for me too now. I also edited the question and I have inserted the code of the form since my form is still not working...maybe you see something that i'm missing...

Comment: Ok, figured out by myself...the input tags where not closed properly <input type="text" id="abc" />  in my form...missing "/"...thank you @Aran for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working, I did suspect bad HTML would be the cause here. Are you happy to accept my answer about as the solution now you've managed to sort?